# How to use Python Scheduler for the whole day

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the [schedule module](https://github.com/dbader/schedule).

Is it possible to set up this scheduler permanently?

I have a VPS and I would like to configure this machine and this scheduler to work for the whole day, even if I turn off putty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what prevents you from running the scheduler as a background process? You could even fire your scheduler program from cron....

Answer (score 0):

Although not a python solution, you can the [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) program to keep a session active between ssh sessions.

[Here's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266571/remotely-starting-a-screen-session-through-ssh-and-closing-the-ssh-session-immed) a useful question over on the unix stackexchange.

Essentially, though, just ssh in, start screen, start your python script, detach from the screen, then exit your ssh session.  If you want to get back to the program, ssh back in, re-attach to your screen session, and you're back to your session.

---

Another possibility is to use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule your jobs.  Without knowing more about your use-case, it's hard to know if this is as well suited to what you need to do as the schedule module but it's certainly possible it could solve your problem.